# Imap_open could not open stream

Tags: php

I'm using imap to get email.

**My code as below:**

```
Imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}inbox', $username, $password);
```

I get error couldn't open stream
Could anyone have any idea to help me solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

You need port 993, the SSL IMAP port.
Port 995 is the SSL POP3 port.

or debug it

```
Imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}inbox', $username, $password)or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

print_r(imap_errors());
```

If it still not solve the issue then past the print_r error here again so we 
can better help you out further.